# Best workflow for any RESTful operation in web CRUD

Tags: rest, crud

As a general rule for any RESTful CRUD operation, I follow these steps:

1. Validating information on client-side
2. Sending required information in JSON format to the server (possibly a web service)
3. Validating information on the server
4. Doing the operation
5. Returning JSON as the result of operation
6. Updating DOM based on server's response

Though this list is general, I think it's the most complete list. The only problem is that, I do it for any and every operation. I mean, DRY (don't repeat yourself) tells us to stop repeating things. Is it considered a repetition? Or should we follow these steps always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can skip validating the data client-side if you wish…

Seriously, those are the necessary minimum for doing a lot of things; you ***must*** validate server side to prevent a whole host of potential problems and the other parts are just fundamental. OK, you can skip the sending to the server, but then you're not interacting with a REST service in the first place. You could also skip updating the DOM, but then you're not showing the results. In other words, every step of that sequence serves its own purpose that is independent from the other ones: they're not redundant.

But that doesn't mean that you should ignore DRY. Not at all. Instead, you should factor out as much of that code as possible into a single place so as to keep the number of repetitions to a minimum. (Maybe even find a framework to do some of that for you.)

Comment: Yeah, I also think about frameworks. But the problem is that, web really has thousands of different scenarios and no framework is complete enough to handle of of'em.

Comment: I think the key to have a basic model to your service that is straight-forward (CRUD is _entirely_ reasonable for simple cases). Then use frameworks to reduce the amount you have to actually write; as long as you keep your model in mind _and_ have certain interfaces clean (notably the messages on the network and the stuff you put in the database) then you'll be fine; frameworks are there to help, to enable, but not replace.